# Different results when using percentile, Top n and Rank X

Tags: powerbi, dax, percentile

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiSlK-qGPwisrTl4Jr2O2_xlWYkc?e=cGwn2h

Kindly help, Firstly, Top N and rankx gives me different sum for my top 25% and I can't figure the reason why.

Attached are the formula used

1. nTop 25 Percent =
   VAR Rank_To_Find = COUNTROWS ( ALL (Sheet1) ) * 0.25
   RETURN
   CALCULATE ( [total sale] , FILTER ( Sheet1,[Rank]<= Rank_To_Find))
2. sales % for 75th percentile and above (using total sales) =
   VAR Percentile75 = PERCENTILEX.INC( Sheet1, Sheet1[Sales],0.75 )
   RETURN
   CALCULATE([Total sale],Sheet1[Sales] >= Percentile75 )

3)Top 25% Total =
var FirstQuart = ROUND(DIVIDE(COUNT(Sheet1[Sales]),4),0)
Return
CALCULATE([total sale],TOPN(FirstQuart, Sheet1,Sheet1Sales],DESC))

All yielded different values. I have the measures in the attached link.

Secondly, I have been trying to work with getting top N orders that sums up to an amount.

For instance, I have a total sales of $1,037,875, I am trying to get the sales that make up the 75th percentile and above (i.e. sums up to 259,468).

I have done the top N using the number of orders (Based on sales).

I guess I will need to use a while or for loop to get it done but do not know how to go about it.

Attached is the link to the sample data file,  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiSlK-qGPwisrTl4Jr2O2_xlWYkc?e=cGwn2h

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measures you are working out the 75th percentile in terms of rows not sales.

**Lets start with what you are trying to achieve**

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to move away from looking at the rows and consider the cumulative value of sales.  With a clean dataset (i.e. remove the blank rows), try the following.

Looking at your dataset, we are trying to establish those sales that fall within the 75th percentile.  They will add up to the boundary of 259,468.89;

Use your existing measure to rank the data by sales

```
Rank = RANKX (all(Sheet1) ,[Total sale])
```

Add a measure to work out the cumulative ranked sales

```
Cumulative Ranked Sale = CALCULATE([Total sale],FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),[Rank]<=MAXX(Sheet1,[Rank])))
```

Now you can work out the sales that 75th percentile, based on cumulative ranked sale value up to 259,468.89.

```
 Cumulative Sales In 75th Percentile = 
 VAR Percentile75 = CALCULATE([Total sale], All(Sheet1))*0.25 

 VAR cumulativeSalesIn75thPercentile  = CALCULATE(
        Sum(Sheet1[Sales]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Sheet1),
             [Cumulative Ranked Sale]<=Percentile75
        )
    )

RETURN cumulativeSalesIn75thPercentile
```

[image: Cumulative 75th percentile example]
I have added a separate measure for displaying Percentile 75 Boundary in the diagram above, but you don't need this for your working as this is a variable in Cumulative Sales 75th Percentile

You need to be mindful that rank will give you multiple values with the same rank which will affect your result.  You also need to consider what you want to happen on the border of 75%, as the break point will not be precise.

You can further extend this logic to cover 50th-75th percentile with additional measures

```
 Cumulative Sales 50-75th Percentile = 
 VAR Percentile75 = CALCULATE([Total sale], All(Sheet1))*0.25 
 VAR Percentile50 = CALCULATE([Total sale], All(Sheet1))*0.5 

 VAR cumulativeSalesIn50thTo75thPercentile  = CALCULATE(
        Sum(Sheet1[Sales]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(Sheet1),
             [Cumulative Ranked Sale]>Percentile75 && 
             [Cumulative Ranked Sale]<=Percentile50
        )
    )

RETURN cumulativeSalesIn50thTo75thPercentile
```

**Returning to your existing workings**

Before we start, the attached sample data is making RowCount and PERCENTILEX.INC inaccurate.  You have 251 orders, however you have 685 rows, the remaining being blank rows.  Keeping your sample data clean, will help your future DAX analysis.

Your "nTop 25 Percent" measure is working out the number of rows (not amount) and providing you with the sum of sales for the top 25 % of rows, ordered by sale value.  The variable

```
VAR Rank_To_Find = COUNTROWS ( ALL (Sheet1) ) * 0.25
```

is equating to 171.25, as you have 685 rows, and therefore 685*0.25 = 171.25.  Thus with this measure you are calculating to total sales for the first 171 rows, ordered by sales amount descending, resulting in $932,906.354.

With your "sales % for 75th percentile and above (using total sales)" measure, PERCENTILE.INC is you are finding the 75th percentile in terms of rows, not cumulative value.  Try changing the k value to anything below 60% (e.g. `PERCENTILEX.INC( Sheet1, Sheet1[Sales],0.60` ) and you'll return the total sales amount.

Comment: Thanks, @Darryl for your time. I have cleaned the data and saw the mistakes. I have gone through the solution and I am not clear about some things. firstly, how do you calculate the top 25% cumulative sale. Secondly, can it be extended to other quartiles such as 2nd 25%, third 25%, and last 25%? I am just confused and a newbie to power bi. 

Thank you

Comment: Bolaji, I have reworked the example to help explain, hopefully this is clearer.  I have also added the 2nd 25% example to hopefully get you going with this.

Comment: @Darryl, Thanks. I have been offline for a while. I have gone through the modification and taking the time to understand it. it works well. Thank you very much.